# Is there a canonical explanation for Lapis Lazuli's power level fluctuations?

Tags: steven-universe

In Lapis Lazuli's initial appearance outside of her mirror, she demonstrated a great deal of power over water, able to lift a quantity of water miles high, wide, and deep (to judge from the driving time to her tower). She was also able to control water duplicates that could fight quite effectively from atop her tower of water.

However, in later episodes, Lapis Lazuli has demonstrated a much more modest control over water, manipulating quantities perhaps the size of modest-size buildings (the water bubble surrounding the barn, for instance).

Obviously, out of universe, antagonists often become less powerful after joining the protagonists, but frequently there's an in-universe reason. Has this apparent disparity ever been canonically explained? For instance, does it take her longer to lift large quantities of water, or did her strength peak after being freed from her imprisonment?

Comment: Well there were several traumatic things that happened in close proximity. Her imprisonment and broken gem, her release, the healing of the gem, and then her forced merge with Jasper. One can envision a scenario where the early events caused her powers to be temporarily hyped up, and the last event causing her to suppress even the normal level of her powers.

Comment: I don't think she lifting less water means she is less powerful. It's just that there was no need to show her full power again.

Comment: It's worth noting that she was severely mentally distressed and suffering from PTSD when she was released from the mirror, so she could have been working on the equivalent of pure instinct - tapping into strength that normally is off-limits because it hurts the user, that sort of thing. More likely is that the amount of water is not an indicator of strength *shrug*.